# Swipe Tabs in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need a suggestion to understand what can prevent a `Tabs` placed inside a `BoxLayout.y()` from changing Tab by swipe.

My main problem is that I wasn't able to create a test case to reproduce this issue. In each individual test case that I tried, the swipe works. However, when I insert the code of each test case into my app, the swipe stops working.

Can you give me some suggestions on what can break the swipe? Thank you

Comment: This will stop working if someone consumes a pointer event and doesn't let it propagate across the chain. E.g. a side menu bar can grab events etc.

Comment: Thank you, I discovered that it's not a problem of pointer event. Moved here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2776

Comment: I close the question because it was solved yesterday by a fix of Steve Hannah, at the Github link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to prevent a tab from swiping:

```
import com.codename1.ui.Tabs; 

Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setSwipeActivated(false);
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have `setSwipeActivated(false)`. I moved the discussion here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2776

Comment: Is it possible that you are using the wrong imports?? I have have checked the approach right away on my machine and it perfectly pulls the method ... see my edited answer ...

Comment: He wants the tabs to swipe and they don't. It's the opposite problem.

Comment: I see ... my  bad